# codeigniter lang->load (ERROR)

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization

I'm using latest codeigniter 3.1.3

There is instruction how to use languages 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html#handling-multiple-languages

```
$idiom = $this->session->get_userdata('language');
$this->lang->load('error_messages', $idiom);  --> gives ERROR (home_view line 14)
$oops = $this->lang->line('message_key'); 
echo $oops;
```

but if i write that lines of code I get following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
>
> Filename: core/Lang.php
>
> Line Number: 109
>
> Backtrace:
>
> **File: .../application/views/home_view.php
>   Line: 14
>   Function: load**
>
> File: .../controllers/Home.php
>   Line: 14
>   Function: view
>
> File: .../project/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

If I remove

```
$idiom = $this->session->get_userdata('language');
$this->lang->load('error_messages', $idiom);  --> ERROR (home_view
```

and place in autoload.php

```
$autoload['language'] = array('error_messages');
```

everything is fine.

But I don't want to autoload all language files since I don't know if user needs everyone of them.

Anyone can help?

thanks

Comment: did you set session..

Comment: check your session data if its array so please convert into string or get specific data from session

Comment: well, thanks it was session problem

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this.Access session variable using  `$this->session->userdata('item_name')`.

```
$idiom = $this->session->userdata('language');
$this->lang->load('error_messages', $idiom);
$oops = $this->lang->line('message_key'); 
echo $oops;
```

**OR**

```
$this->config->set_item('language', $idiom );//dynamically set language
$this->lang->load('error_messages');//load lang file

$oops = $this->lang->line('message_key'); 
echo $oops;
```

Hope it helps you.

For more see here https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: it was a problem with the session. Session data wasn't properly set

Comment: get session variable using `userdata()` not `get_userdata()`.

Comment: see in answer.hope you will get variable correctly.